# fast Cartesian to Polar to Cartesian in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, numpy

I want to transform in Python 2d arrays/images to polar, process then, and subsequently transform them back to cartesian. The following is the result from ImajeJ [Polar Transformer](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/polar-transformer.html) plugin (used on the concentric circles of the sample code):

[image]

The number and dims of the images is quite large so I was checking whether openCV has a fast and simple way to do this.

I read about cv. `CartToPolar` and `PolarToCart` but I failed to use it. I understand better the `LogPolar` where the input and output are arrays, and where you can set the center, interpolation,and inversion (i.e `CV_WARP_INVERSE_MAP`). Is there a way to use CartToPolar/PolarToCart in an similar fashion?

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv

    #sample 2D array that featues concentric circles
    circlesArr = np.ndarray((512,512),dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(10,600,10): cv.Circle(circlesArr,(256,256),i-10,np.random.randint(60,500),thickness=4)

    #logpolar
    lp = np.ndarray((512,512),dtype=np.float32)
    cv.LogPolar(circlesArr,lp,(256,256),100,cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)

    #logpolar Inverse
    lpinv = np.ndarray((512,512),dtype=np.float32)
    cv.LogPolar(lp,lpinv,(256,256),100, cv.CV_WARP_INVERSE_MAP + cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)

    #display images
    from scipy.misc import toimage
    toimage(lp, mode="L").show()
    toimage(lpinv, mode="L").show()
```

This is for a tomography (CT) workflow where rings artifacts can be filtered out easier if they appear as lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the CV source code mentions a `LinearPolar`.  it doesn't seem to be documented, but appears to be similar to `LogPolar`.  have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you very very much! Indeed `LinearPolar` does what it says. Unfortunately by using `import cv` it was not available, but I tried `from opencv import cv` and then `cv.cvLinearPolar` and works. Next days I'll try it's performance in large datasets. Thank you!

Comment: cool.  i wonder why it's not visible?  i'll try filing a bug report.

Answer (score 7):

Latest versions of opencv supports a function cv2.linearPolar.
This may be another solution that does not involve the use of opencv:

```
def polar2cart(r, theta, center):

    x = r  * np.cos(theta) + center[0]
    y = r  * np.sin(theta) + center[1]
    return x, y

def img2polar(img, center, final_radius, initial_radius = None, phase_width = 3000):

    if initial_radius is None:
        initial_radius = 0

    theta , R = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, phase_width), 
                            np.arange(initial_radius, final_radius))

    Xcart, Ycart = polar2cart(R, theta, center)

    Xcart = Xcart.astype(int)
    Ycart = Ycart.astype(int)

    if img.ndim ==3:
        polar_img = img[Ycart,Xcart,:]
        polar_img = np.reshape(polar_img,(final_radius-initial_radius,phase_width,3))
    else:
        polar_img = img[Ycart,Xcart]
        polar_img = np.reshape(polar_img,(final_radius-initial_radius,phase_width))

    return polar_img
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro- I tried to solve this problem in this way too, and I wrote similar code, although I used a loop instead of meshgrid (I've never seen that before); do you know how well this performs? Mine was taking on the order of 1s for a VGA image - too long.

Comment: OK, I have tested your code and it is VERY fast compared with my iterative solution- plus I learned something new- thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of the log-polar transform implemented using SciPy:

https://github.com/stefanv/supreme/blob/master/supreme/transform/transform.py#L51

Given that this is only a coordinate transformation, it should be easier to adapt to your problem than the OpenCV version.

Comment: Dear Stefan, thank you very much for you feedback. I'll check and benchmark your implementation the next days. Btw, I ended up browsing Supreme and seems very interesting. Have you published any article about it?

Comment: @Papado I never saw your comment, but yes--there's a paper on arXiv and a dissertation.  By the way, the log polar transform can now be implemented on top of scikit-image in about 5 lines of code, using ``skimage.transform.warp``.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I'm looking for something similar and now you can do it round trip with cv2 as follow:

```
import cv2
import math

# img -> your image 
h, w = img.shape[:2]
img_center = (h/2, w/2)
img_radius = math.hypot(h/2, w/2)

cart_2_polar_flag = cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS
img_forth = cv2.linearPolar(img, img_center, img_radius, cart_2_polar_flag)


polar_2_cart_flag = cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP
img_back = cv2.linearPolar(img_forth, img_center, img_radius, polar_2_cart_flag)
```