# Can't transform image into polar. Python, OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I'm trying to implement ring artefact reduction algorithm using python. The first step is to transform image from cartesian to polar. I suppose that I can use opencv to do that. In this topic [fast Cartesian to Polar to Cartesian in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924135/fast-cartesian-to-polar-to-cartesian-in-python) author managed to use LinearPolar function but it doesn't work on my computer.

I tried the following way:

```
import cv
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('artifact.png', 0)
img1 = cv2.imread('artifact.png', 0) 
cv.LinearPolar(cv.fromarray(img),cv.fromarray(img1),(130,110), 1 ,cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
```

But it returned an error :
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LinearPolar'

So is there any way to use this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is `cv2.linearPolar` - it's objecting to the capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

In the recently updated versions you do not need to pass the output array to the function. The output can be assigned to a variable:

```
result = cv2.linearPolar(image, (50, 50), 1.0, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using cv2.LinearPolar ?

https://fossies.org/dox/opencv-3.1.0/logpolar_8py_source.html

Comment: I tried, but it also returned: 'module' object has no attribute 'LinearPolar'.